# Why are ionic reactions very fast in aqueous medium?

Tags: water, ionic-compounds

(No, I am not talking about why Ionic Reactions are faster than Covalent reaction.)

This question has me stumped. I mean, at first it looks obvious; water is *polar* in nature, but what exactly does that help with?  Also, can ionic reactions even happen in non-aqueous mediums?

Comment: What do ionic and covalent reactions mean?

Comment: @orthocresol I think the asker means the difference between reactions involving only neutral species and reactions involving oppositely charged species.

Answer (score 1):

Water has a permanent dipole character, which means it has a slight positive and negative charge permanently in it (due to electronegativity difference). So, in case of an ionic reaction, it helps in easier solvation of ions by pulling them with its charged centres (positive centre attracts negative ions and negative centre attracts positive ions)

*Aqueous* is a term specially for water as a solvent. Any polar solvent can support ionic reactions.